# Approval process - Notification email is not required

Tags: community, administration

In approval process, can we stop auto generated mail (when submitter submit any record in the meantime approver receive an email) ..

i want to stop that mail (approver will not receive any type of notification email from submitter end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the standard approval email. This is proposed as an Idea for Idea Exchange for future release (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq74AAC)

To serve your purpose, on the user record, there is a field called "Receive Approval Request Emails". If you change this to "never" the user will not receive emails from approval process.

[image: Approval Email Settings]

Please revert in case you need more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best answer, but what I could think of is maybe you can make the Manager field for each User Account empty, then Manager won't be getting notified.